# Two Squid chaining

Tags: proxy, squid

I have two squid servers, Squid A and Squid B.

Squid A transparently caches for the local network.

I would like to set up Squid A so that on a request for an URL matching a regexp, instead of serving the request as normal, it "redirects" through Squid B so that Squid B serves the request, passes the result back to Squid A which passes it onto the client.

How do I set up the config file for Squid A to do this?

Comment: Buh?                ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following in squid A configuration (normally /etc/squid/squid.conf)

```
cache_peer <squid server B IP> parent <server B squid port> 3130 no-query no-digest no-netdb-exchange 

acl otherproxy url_regex "/etc/squid/divert.txt"
cache_peer_access <Squid server B IP> allow otherproxy
never_direct allow otherproxy
cache_peer_access <squid server B IP> deny all
```

And following in squid B configuration at top of other acls

```
acl A_proxy src <Squid server A IP>/32
http_access allow A_proxy
```

After that you can add regular expressions to file /etc/squid/divert.txt and reload squid. The matching URLs will be requested from Server B and not directly.

The reason why I mentioned adding acl on proxy B too is too avoid authentication, connection limit, etc. settings on proxy B affecting clients of proxy A as such problems are very hard to debug. So it is better to allow all requests from proxy A to proxy B. If you want to block something block it in both proxy configurations.

Answer (score 1):

you want something like the following in squid A's squid.conf.  use it as an example and tweak to suit your exact requirements.

```
# define squid B as a parent
cache_peer squid.b.example.com parent 3128 3130 default

# create ACLs for any domains or IP address ranges that you
# don't want to get from the parent (squid B). for example:
acl local_domains domain your.local.domains.here
acl local_ip dst your.local.ip.addresses.here
always_direct_allow local_domains
always_direct allow local_ip

# and deny direct access to everything else
never_direct allow all
```

Answer (score -1):

Squid specifically has a feature supporting hierarchic organization of proxy servers. The [squid manual page](http://www.deckle.co.za/squid-users-guide/Squid_Configuration_Basics#Communicating_with_other_proxy_servers) has excellent documentation on that topic.